# Retrieving data from array of array objects

Tags: json, node.js

In my application i am trying to return javascript object of employee who works in all projects. My array of data is like:

```
   var data = [
{
    projectName: "project1", projectId: 1,
    employees: [
        {fullName: "John Doe", employeeId: 1},
        {fullName: "Jane Smith", employeeId: 2}
    ]
},

{
    projectName: "project2", projectId: 2,
    employees: [
        {fullName: "John Doe", employeeId: 1},
        {fullName: "Mary Jones", employeeId: 3},
        {fullName: "Bill Evans", employeeId: 4}
    ]
}
```

];

I need to search for employeeid 1 and return both projects. How do i search it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use `Array.filter` and `Array.findIndex`.

**UPD:**
since Array.findIndex is a new feature in ES6, maybe not supported by some browsers, but it has a polyfill for those unsupported browsers to use, see documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)）.

```
function doFilter(arr) {
  return arr.filter(function(item) {
    return item.employees.findIndex(function(employee) {
      return employee.employeeId === 1;
    }) > -1;
 });
}
```

this code snippet will return the target project array which contains the employee with an ID of 1.

```js
var data = [{
    projectName: "project1",
    projectId: 1,
    employees: [{
        fullName: "John Doe",
        employeeId: 1
      },
      {
        fullName: "Jane Smith",
        employeeId: 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    projectName: "project2",
    projectId: 2,
    employees: [{
        fullName: "John Doe",
        employeeId: 1
      },
      {
        fullName: "Mary Jones",
        employeeId: 3
      },
      {
        fullName: "Bill Evans",
        employeeId: 4
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    projectName: "project3",
    projectId: 3,
    employees: [{
      fullName: "Jane Smith",
      employeeId: 2
    }]
  }
];

function doFilter(arr) {
  return arr.filter(function(item) {
    return item.employees.findIndex(function(employee) {
      return employee.employeeId === 1;
    }) > -1;
  });
}
console.log(doFilter(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is the code you're looking for:

```
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++)
 {
    emp=data[i].employees;
    for(j=0;j<emp.length;j++)
    {
        if(emp[j].employeeId==1)
          console.log('Project of' + emp[j].fullName + 'is = ' + data[i].projectName)
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh yes. I totally forgot. There is an inbuilt `filter` function for array.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works Fine

```js
var data = [{
    projectName: "project1",
    projectId: 1,
    employees: [{
        fullName: "John Doe",
        employeeId: 1
      },
      {
        fullName: "Jane Smith",
        employeeId: 5
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    projectName: "project2",
    projectId: 2,
    employees: [{
        fullName: "John Doe",
        employeeId: 1
      },
      {
        fullName: "Mary Jones",
        employeeId: 3
      },
      {
        fullName: "Bill Evans",
        employeeId: 4
      }
    ]
  }
];

function getEmployeeById(id) {
  var e = $.map(data, function(a) {
    var r = $.grep(a.employees, function(b) {
      return b.employeeId == id;
    });
    if (r.length) {
      console.log(a.projectName, r[0].fullName)
    }
  });
}
getEmployeeById(1)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be as simple as this. Just iterate and compare.
https://jsfiddle.net/

```
for( i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
    for( j=0;j<data[i].employees.length;j++)
  {
     if (data[i].employees[j].employeeId == 1)
      console.log(data[i].projectId);
  }
}
```